# Change helptext icon color of lightning-input LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-experience, css, lightninginput

The issue Im facing is that I want to customize the color of the helptext associated with a lightning-input element in a Salesforce Lightning Web Component (LWC). Im looking for a way to change the icon color while respecting the encapsulation provided by the shadow DOM.

here is the html:

```
<lightning-input type="email" label={customLabels.labelEmail} placeholder={customLabels.initTextBoxPlaceholder}
                         message-when-pattern-mismatch={customLabels.initTextBoxErrorPatternMismatch}
                         max-length=80 value={email} required="true"
                         onchange={emailValueChanged} field-level-help={customLabels.initEmailHelpText}
                         message-when-type-mismatch={customLabels.initTextBoxErrorPatternMismatch}
                         message-when-value-missing={customLabels.initTextBoxErrorPatternMismatch}></lightning-input>
```

Currently it looks like this:
[image]